# Can possible to regenerate login session before it expire in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have set the session expiration time by aprox 2 hour.

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

now user put a requirement for functionality like
after user login in a system and put the system in idle mode then after 2 hours login session will expire. but before session expire system will popup a message like

> Your Login session will expire in particular time , are u want to
>   regenerate session again ?

if user click on yes then system will automatically regenerate its session.

Can this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript on (every) view page where you want pop up displayed with timeout function that is set to `7200 - secondsBeforeExpiration`. You can show it as popup, modal, appended div etc. Basically when page is opened, JS counter starts and after specific time let's say 6900 seconds, confirmation box is up, where answer yes reload location or something similar. Maybe even would be better to use AJAX to [regenerate session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632175/is-it-possible-to-regenerate-code-igniter-sessions-manually). And [here you can see](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) how JS `setTimeout()` function works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```

This will destroy the session.